How to cope with text-shadow property rendering inconsistently in Safari?
Tested background for future search reference:

Mac Sonoma 14.5
Safari 17.5
Firefox 128.0 (64-bit)
Chrome 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (arm64)

** This question differ to the existing questions, it focuses on text-shadow inconsistency in Safari and what solutions to cope with it rather than discussing about text-stroke.
I discover the characteristic of the text-shadow while using text-stroke. That's why it might be misunderstood to be text-stroke oriented. The other question didn't mention the text-shadow problem in Safari.
I am doing text styling for a web project. At first, I wanted to add a stroke to the text.
But soon I found out that the text-stroke property actually gives an inner stroke and cannot be turned into an outer stroke. So, I came up with a solution by creating a pseudo-element with the same text to mimic an outer stroke effect. This method comes from my habit of doing layouts in Photoshop or Illustrator. A text shadow is also added to give a sense of depth.
The outcome looks great, but then I found another problem in Safari. Safari on Mac, iPhone, and iPad renders the text-shadow differently.
The problem arises because the text-shadow in Safari considers everything inside the element, including the pseudo-element. So, the shadow looks different. I am not sure if there is any description of the CSS specification implementation in the rendering engine. As far as I have tested with Firefox and Chrome, they look the same.
I am not sure if it is a Safari bug or an implementation philosophy difference. I have done a couple of tests, workarounds, and solutions which I will summarize later as a reference answer.
Here is an illustration to the above.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .text-shadow {
            position: relative;
            text-shadow: 2px 4px 7px #333333 !important;
            font-size: 80px !important;
            color: #fbff00 !important;
            text-transform: uppercase !important;
        }

        .text-shadow::before {
            content: attr(data-content);
            color: black;
            -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1em black;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-shadow" data-content="Hello! Is it different in Safari?">Hello! Is it different in Safari?</div>
</body>
</html>




This question is similar to: Why does -webkit-text-stroke look different on Chrome and Safari?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

But I am focus on text-shadow problem, not the stroke. And the solution resolving the problem is different because I am focusing on how to get a consitent shadow as suggested clearly on the title (text-shadow).
